# In TFS 2010, is there a way to search multiple projects for all work items under a specific iteration?

Tags: tfs

We can search for work items under an iteration per project, but we'd like to search in ALL of our projects, if possible.

The My/Team query builder won't let you use a wildcard in the Iteration Path, which means you must select a specific iteration in the Iteration Path 'Value' dropdown...

I figure we may be able to run a SQL query on the backend, but there is red tape involved in that solution...are there any other solutions?

As to the 'why' question:  we would like to track all open 'hotfix' work for all of the projects.  Aside from having someone enter the term hotfix into the title of a work item (which introduces human error, but would be searchable), we're not quite sure how to do this by searching for iteration.

Comment: What happens if you just don't specify the project in the query?

Comment: Area and iteration paths also contain the project name.

Comment: I agree with John, don't use the project = @project in the query and don't filter with the area or iteration.  Just filter with work item type = hotfix type (task/bugs/etc.) and use tags.  If you tag all you hotfix in all your projects with the same tag (Hotfix) you should get them all.

Comment: Thanks @Etienne.  I'll see if any of the sys admins have enough knowledge to add a new work item type.  I think the simplest solution may be for us to have someone enter Hotfix in the title or description.  Hopefully when we upgrade to 2013 they'll get a process together :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this without a great number of "or".

You should consider merging the team projects that you are encountering this issue with. In addition you should upgrade TFS to take advantage of the new team entity for splitting up the work.

http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project/

Comment: Thanks MrHinsh.  Unfortunately TFS 2010 was never setup properly (or used with a standard process), so we're trying to find work arounds with the as-is functionality.  We'll hopefully go to 2013 relatively soon...and hopefully this time we'll start with proper processes and knowledge.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help 